# Find and Replace Color in Texture2D/Sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, sprite, renderer

[image]

I would like to change the pants color from blue (#0088f0) to red (#f00000) directly in the code (it's a 2D sprite).

I searched a lot but didn't find something working with a sprite without recoloring specifics pixels (setPixel())..ect..

Can't we just replace a color by another one on a sprite somehow? like the rendering of the RGB of BLUE is equal to RED by default for this sprite ?

Comment: You can tint the color inside of the sprite inspector. But to have good result you would have to make these pants white.

Comment: Add new material with color....

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve what you want with using shaders. You need to create new material, assign shader to it, and then, assign this material to the image component on the scene. Here is shader code:

```
Shader "PiotrMitrega/ColorSwap"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Sprite", 2D) = "white" {}
        _ColorToChange("Color You Want To Change", Color) = (0,0,1,1)
        _DesiredColor("Desired Color ", Color) = (1,0,0,1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "RenderType" = "Opaque"
            "Queue" = "Transparent+1"
        }

        Pass
        {
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile DUMMY PIXELSNAP_ON

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _ColorToChange;
        float4 _DesiredColor;

        struct Vertex
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv_MainTex : TEXCOORD0;
            float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        struct Fragment
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv_MainTex : TEXCOORD0;
            float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        Fragment vert(Vertex v)
        {
            Fragment o;

            o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.uv_MainTex = v.uv_MainTex;
            o.uv2 = v.uv2;

            return o;
        }

        float4 frag(Fragment IN) : COLOR
        {
            half4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);

                if (c.r >= _ColorToChange.r - 0.005 && c.r <= _ColorToChange.r + 0.005
                && c.g >= _ColorToChange.g - 0.005 && c.g <= _ColorToChange.g + 0.005
                    && c.b >= _ColorToChange.b - 0.005 && c.b <= _ColorToChange.b + 0.005)
            {
                return _DesiredColor;
            }

            return c;
        }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not so qualified in writing shader, so it definately can be written better than this. But anyways, it does the job.

[That's how you should setup this on the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLUvj.png)

[Result of using shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VNJQ.png)

However, you can see it's not working on edges. That's because your texture is made like this. Body, legs and head are not solid color. So it swapped only on one, particular color.

Please keep in mind that if you won't set "Point" filter mode in texture import settings, your edges will be even more blurry (even if your texture has solid colors everywhere)

So, if you have solid colors everywhere on your texture, shader would work fine exactly how it is. But, for example texture given (with blurry edges) we could use another approach. We can manually define min/max values for separately r,g,b components and swap color for everything inside desired range.
Here's shader code for that:

```
Shader "PiotrMitrega/ColorSwap-Range"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Sprite", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MinG("Minimum Green Value", Float) = 0.5
        _MaxG("Maximum Green Value", Float) = 1
        _MinB("Minimum Blue Value", Float) = 0.5
        _MaxB("Maximum Blue Value", Float) = 1
        _MinR("Minimum Red Value", Float) = 0.5
        _MaxR("Maximum Red Value", Float) = 1
        _DesiredColor("Desired Color ", Color) = (1,0,0,1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "RenderType" = "Opaque"
            "Queue" = "Transparent+1"
        }

        Pass
        {
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile DUMMY PIXELSNAP_ON

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _DesiredColor;
        float _MinG;
        float _MaxG;
        float _MinB;
        float _MaxB;
        float _MinR;
        float _MaxR;

        struct Vertex
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv_MainTex : TEXCOORD0;
            float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        struct Fragment
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv_MainTex : TEXCOORD0;
            float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        Fragment vert(Vertex v)
        {
            Fragment o;

            o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.uv_MainTex = v.uv_MainTex;
            o.uv2 = v.uv2;

            return o;
        }

        float4 frag(Fragment IN) : COLOR
        {
            half4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            if (c.g >= _MinG && c.g <= _MaxG
                && c.r >= _MinR && c.r <= _MaxR
                && c.b >= _MinB && c.b <= _MaxB)
            {
                return _DesiredColor;
            }

            return c;
        }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

By playing a little bit with min/max values you will definately be able to get desired effect.

If you want to have couple of predefined effects, like "red shirt", "brown pants' etc, you should create couple of materials, change their parameters to match your requirements, and then just swap depending on your current needs.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use another material instead of default material. You can change color or cut off sprite it seem posible.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html